# Does webkit rendering download web-page's content e.g., images, text?

Tags: python, browser, webkit, html-rendering

I need to obtain HTML DOM trees of a couple of websites using pywebkit using python code, [link](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/07/07/downloading-a-pages-content-with-python-and-webkit/). To be on the safe side (by avoiding illegal content download), I want to know whether the pywebkit rendering would download and save content(e.g., images, videos, etc) to my local storage or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about browser cache and not intentional save actions.

Webkit is a full fledged browser and will honour what site indicates it to do. If site allows caching of resources, it will cache it on local storage. If site says don't cache, it will not.

Comment: "+1" thanks, yes, it does download content (i had already figured it out) while rendering javascripts. It could be confirmed by looking at HTTP traffic.